# Angular shared component referencing old view when used

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Working with Ionic framework, I have an image upload form component which is shared amongst other pages in the application so this form exists in multiple places.

It features an `@Output` and `EventEmitter` it has an input field with `(change)` decorator to detect when an image is populated (I believe this is where the issue is)
when I navigate to the first page and use it is fine, when I navigate to another page within the app and use it references the previous page and in turn uploads the image to the wrong API endpoint.

How can I destroy an instance of a component after navigation to another page or at least allow the same component to exist on multiple pages as its own unique instance.

in the component html:

```
<input id="fileInput" type="file" accept="image/*" class="inputfile" (change)="onFileChange($event)" />
<ion-button [hidden]="!showOptions || cordova" class="resetBtn">
  <label class="resetIcon" for="fileInput">
    <ion-icon class="resetIcon" color="generic" name="image"></ion-icon>
  </label>
</ion-button>
```

and in the component.ts:

```
onFileChange(event: any) {
    let reader = new FileReader()
    ... do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is not to try to catch it afterwards, but to always set it to a sensible default at the beginning.

Comment: Im not sure I understand, can you elaborate